# Thread safe associative container

Tags: c++, thread-safety, containers, associative

I have a map which looks like this: `std::map<int, class A*> m`. I have two threads: one of them is reading `m` and updating the values of the object contained and the other one is reading and writing (removing elements). Is there a way to make it thread-safe without using mutexes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to make it thread-safe without using mutexes?

No.

You might be able to write your own lock-free map, perhaps with ideas like [this](http://erdani.com/publications/cuj-2004-12.pdf), or try third-party libraries like [this](http://libcds.sourceforge.net/), but the standard map gives no thread safety guarantees.